# How to get epoch value from JQueryM datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker, epoch

I'm trying to get the epoch date from my datepicker. I have tried putting an altField with an altFormat on the datepicker via HTML but when trying to get the value back using JavaScript it's null:

HTML -

```
 <input onchange='Refresh()' name="logging_from" id="logging_from" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox","overrideDateFormat":"%d-%b-%y", "showInitialValue":true, "altField": "#epochdate","altFormat": "@" }'>
```

JavaScript -

```
    var loggingfromactual = document.getElementById("epochdate").value;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

Handle the change event of the input, get the date and convert to epoch (date.getTime() / 1000)

```
<input name="logging_from" id="logging_from" type="text" data-role="datebox" 
data-options='{
   "useNewStyle":true, 
   "mode": "calbox",
   "overrideDateFormat":"%d-%b-%y"
}' />

$("#logging_from").on("change", function(){
    alert("Epoch of sel date is " + dateToEpoch($(this).datebox('getTheDate')));   
});

function dateToEpoch(thedate){
    return thedate.getTime() / 1000;   
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sg5gm84z/)**

**OR**, add a close callback on the calendar:

```
<input name="logging_from" id="logging_from" type="text" data-role="datebox"
        data-options='{
           "useNewStyle":true, 
           "mode": "calbox",
           "overrideDateFormat":"%d-%b-%y" ,
            "closeCallback":"onCloseCalendar",
            "closeCallbackArgs":["out_date"]
        }' />

function onCloseCalendar(thedate){
    alert("Epoch for sel date is " + dateToEpoch(thedate));
}

function dateToEpoch(thedate){
    return thedate.getTime() / 1000;   
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sg5gm84z/1/)**

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, but is there a way to get the epoch value of the calendar without closing it? - because I'm trying to store the epoch value but its null until both dates (I'm using this on two calendars - to and from dates) on the calendar have been selected - thanks.